# Grouping and Combining Observables in RxJava

Tags: rx-java2

I would like to do the following with RxJava

```
class Invoice(val dayOfMonth:Int,val amount:Int)
```

below is the sample monthInvoices:List< Invoice > to process

```
Invoice(3,100)
Invoice(3,150)
Invoice(3,50)
Invoice(4,350)
Invoice(8,400)
Invoice(8,100)
```

First, I would like to group it by the day of the month like the following

```
Invoice(3,300)
Invoice(4,350)
Invoice(8,500)
```

Then I would like to create a list containing all the days of the month. Say, we are having 30 days for this month, then the output list must contain inserting a empty Invoice object with 0 amount for the days where there is no invoice

Desired output List

```
Invoice(1,0) //Since day 1 is not in the group summed list
Invoice(2,0) //day 2 is also not there
Invoice(3,300)
Invoice(4,350)
Invoice(5,0) 
Invoice(6,0)
Invoice(7,0)
Invoice(8,500)
…..
Invoice(30,0)
```

Hope I have explained the need clearly. Can anyone please answer me a solution to do it entirely using RxJava?

Comment: why rx ? I do not see anything reactive in this ? why not juste Java Stream ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
fun task(invoices: List<Invoice>) =
    Observable.fromIterable(invoices)
        .groupBy { it.dayOfMonth }
        .flatMapSingle { group -> group.reduce(0) { t1, t2 -> t1 + t2.amount }
            .map { group.key to it }}
        .toMap({ it.first }, { it.second })
        .flatMapObservable { map ->
            Observable.range(1, 30)
                .map { Invoice(it, map[it] ?: 0) }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved much more easily using the collection operators inside Kotlin's standard library, but in pure RxJava you can do this by using `groupBy` and `reduce`.

```
    val invoices = listOf(
        Invoice(3, 100),
        Invoice(3, 150),
        Invoice(3, 50),
        Invoice(4, 350),
        Invoice(8, 400),
        Invoice(8, 100)
    )

    Observable.range(1, 30)
        .map { Invoice(it, 0) } // Create an Observable of Invoice([day], 0)
        .mergeWith(Observable.fromIterable(invoices))
        .groupBy { it.dayOfMonth } // Merge the sources and groupBy day
        .flatMapMaybe { group ->
            group.reduce { t1: Invoice, t2: Invoice ->
                Invoice(t1.dayOfMonth, t1.amount + t2.amount) // Reduce each group into a single Invoice
            }
        }
        .subscribe {
            // Optionally you can call toList before this if you want to aggregate the emissions into a single list
            println(it)
        }
```